# Fierce and Cruel Gladiator vendors? World of Warcraft Battle for Azeroth 8.0.1

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I seem to be lost, I remember seeing a vendor for Fierce/Cruel gladiator sets before launch but now I can't seem to find them anymore.

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're in Dalaran (Broken Isles)

For Alliance:

[Lieutenant Surtees](https://www.wowhead.com/npc=106930/lieutenant-surtees) in the Greyfang Enclave

[image]

For Horde:

[Apothecary Lee](https://www.wowhead.com/npc=119486/apothecary-lee) in Windrunner's Sanctuary

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried looking everywhere but just completely failed to find it